# PowerShell returning Length property on SELECT *

Tags: powershell

I was trying to get all the string properties and methods.  And instead of >"1,2,3,4,5,6" | Get-Member just out of curiosity I tried the following command and it gives me the Length property of String object. I thought it will give me error or no output.  Any idea why it is doing this?  Or How PowerShell interprets SELECT command?

```
    PS C:>"1,2,3,4,5,6" | SELECT * 

    Length  
    -----------

    11
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Length` is the only property of `System.String` the rest of the members are methods. You can see this by doing:

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6" | Get-Member
```

`Select` is an alias for `Select-Object`. `Select-Object -Property *` says list all properties and property values of the incoming object.

You can see all the members of `System.String` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) and read up on the `Select-Object` cmdlet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315291.aspx).

Comment: Oh! I never noticed that it has only one property. So this might be stupid question but would it in any case PS would include methods in select.

Comment: @Mitul Nope `Select-Object` only returns you properties. It will also return you a custom object if you only select a subset of the incoming objects properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do when parsing text.  You can use PSCX Get-TypeName to debug type issues from normal PowerShell session (can use breakpoints in ISE window).